# getting error and help me to solve this c

Tags: c, object, struct, resolve

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
struct books
{
    char book_name[100];
    char book_author[100];
    int book_id;
};
void print(int j,book[j])
{
        printf("The name of book %d is %s",j,book.book_name);
        printf("\nThe author of book %d is %s",j,book.book_author);
        printf("\nThe id of book %d is %d",j,book.book_id);
}
int main()
{
    int b;
    printf("Enter the number of books :");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    for(int i=1;i<=b;i++)
    {
        struct books book[i];
        printf("Enter the details of book %d /n",i);
        printf("Enter the book %d name:",i);
        scanf("%s",&book[i].book_name);
        printf("\n Enter the author of book %d :",i);
        scanf("%s",&book[i].book_author);
        printf("\n Enter the id of book %d :",i);
        scanf("%d",&book[i].book_id);
    }
    printf("\n The details of the books you entered are given below:\n");
    for(int j=1;j<=b;j++)
    {
        print(int j,book[j]);
    }
    getch();
return 0;
}
```

ERror:
-->
[Error] 'book' was not declared in this scope in print function... how can i change the scope of the struct object to global?
I am creating a library like environment and printing the name of books and its details using the structures .but the objects created are beyond the scope.it says as in error log.
Help me to resolve the prblm.

Comment: Generally, put the newline at the end of each `printf()` statement. Don't put it at the beginning; don't leave the last line of output without a newline.  All else apart, the output is not guaranteed to appear on a screen until you do output a newline (though input functions like `getch()` and `scanf()` often do flush `stdout` before reading any input.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed code :- see comments

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
struct books
{
    char book_name[100];
    char book_author[100];
    int book_id;
};
void print(int j,struct books book ) //Fix arguments use the struct
{
        printf("The name of book %d is %s",j,book.book_name);
        printf("\nThe author of book %d is %s",j,book.book_author);
        printf("\nThe id of book %d is %d",j,book.book_id);
}
int main()
{
    int b;
    printf("Enter the number of books :");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    struct books book[b];  // Declare the array of struct outside.
    for(int i=1;i<=b;i++)
    {
         // Use \n not /n for newline
        printf("Enter the details of book %d \n",i); 
        printf("Enter the book %d name:",i);

        scanf("%s",book[i].book_name);  // Remove & sign, %s expects a char *
        printf("\n Enter the author of book %d :",i);

        scanf("%s",book[i].book_author); // Remove & sign,  %s expects a char *
        printf("\n Enter the id of book %d :",i);
        scanf("%d",&book[i].book_id);
    }
    printf("\n The details of the books you entered are given below:\n");
    for(int j=1;j<=b;j++)
    {
        print(j,book[j]);
    }
    getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note the residual problems (in the original code as well as your revision) that the name of the book cannot contain any spaces, and that the name of the author cannot contain any spaces.  Also, the `scanf()` calls are never checked to ensure that data is read.

Answer (score 0):

```
void print(int j,book[j])
```

should be

```
void print(int j , struct books *books)
```

and this

```
    printf("The name of book %d is %s",j,book.book_name);
    printf("\nThe author of book %d is %s",j,book.book_author);
    printf("\nThe id of book %d is %d",j,book.book_id);
```

should be

```
    printf("The name of book %d is %s",j,books-<book_name);
    printf("\nThe author of book %d is %s",j,books->book_author);
    printf("\nThe id of book %d is %d",j,books->book_id);
```

and here you need to change:

```
    print(int j,book[j]);
```

to

```
    print(int j, &book[j]);
```

When you declare a function like here

```
void print(int j,book[j])
```

You also have to specify the type, which is missing. If you intended to use the array directly, without passing it to print, then you would have to make it global, and then you don't need to pass it in the function. Havign it as argument is usually better though, because the code is then better isolated.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add it. :)

Comment: Expected primary expression before [ token.

Comment: Note that the call to the function is `print(j, book[j]);` which passes the structure by value, not as a pointer.  It also passes the actual book, not the start of the array.  Thus, you could have `void print(int j, struct books book)` and the call as currently written, or you could use `void print(int j, struct books *book)` and modify the print statements like `printf("The name of book %d is %s", j, book->book_name);` and the call like `print(j, &book[j]);`.  I'm not sure I understand the 'primary expression' error yet — it doesn't look reasonable.

Comment: Updated the adress operator